# How to find TimeZoneInfo by Name

Tags: c#

I know we can find timezone information by id using

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
```

Is there anything we can use to get by name ?

```
example: 
TimeZoneInfo timeZone2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneByName("(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West");
```

There is no inbuilt method like this .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name what you shown is display name. A simple linq query can bring you that.

```
string displayName = "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West";
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DisplayName == displayName);
```

Comment: Hah, that's nice to know.

Comment: Please note that this answer depends on the language of installed .NET framework on executing machine.